# How to get UTF-8 encoded value of stdin?

Tags: c, utf-8, stdin, stdio

I need to write a program in ANSI C that will display the UTF-8 encoded hexadecimal values of each character of stdin, regardless of the character encoding that stdin uses. For example,

```
AÀĀ
```

yields

```
41
C0
0100
```

Is there a function in C that will convert the character encoding to UTF-8?

Comment: Those values are not the UTF-8 values for those three characters. UTF-8 never uses '01' or '00' as part of the representation of a character.

Comment: Judging by the example you give, you want to print the Unicode code points, not the UTF-8 hex values (which would be 41 c380 c480).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put UTF-8 out unless you *know* what is coming in. If you know the encoding of stdin, you can use `iconv` or even ICU4C to convert to UTF-8, and then dump hex in the usual sort of way. In some cases you could assume that stdin conforms to the locale specified in the LANG environment variable, but nothing stops someone from running:

```
yourprogram < SomeFileFullOfISO-2022-JP
```

Comment: Well, it's possible to do a qualified guess. It's quite unlikely that anything but UTF-8 will validate as UTF-8 for example.